# How to convert java.util.List[java.lang.Long], to java.util.List[Long]

Tags: java, scala

I'm working with the following class and have trouble converting a scala long list to java.util.List[Long]:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.twitter.TwitterSource

  class myFilterEndpoint2 extends TwitterSource.EndpointInitializer with Serializable {
    override def createEndpoint(): StreamingEndpoint = {
      val customEndpoint2 = new StatusesFilterEndpoint()
      customEndpoint2.followings(List[Long](545543434).asJava)
      return customEndpoint2
    }
  }
```

I'm getting the error:

> Type mismatch, expected: java.util.List[java.lang.Long], actual:
>   java.util.List[Long]

How can I do the conversion properly?

Comment: `List[java.lang.Long](545543434).asJava` would be the simplest way, I think. Too short for an answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still getting to grips with the language. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are converting scala List[..] into java equivalent with `asJava` method call. What you need to do is to convert the elements themselves. To do that you can simply map all the elements with longToLong eg.

```
customEndpoint2.followings(List[Long](545543434L).map(long2Long).asJava)
```